# Can I generate multiple random uint8 from a uint256?

Tags: chainlink, randomness, random, vrf

The chainlink VRF returns a uint256, for my application I need a uint8. If I utilize one uint256 and break it up into separate uint8 is that still secure as a source of randomness? Also, what's the most gas efficient way to do this? Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I will show you a couple of different ways that you can break down a `uint256` value into individual 8-bit (1 byte) values that you can use.
I suggest you use `uint8` since 1 bytes is 8 bits, so is easier to work with this.

The functions `break256BitsIntegerIntoBytesArrayOf1Byte` and `break256BitsIntegerIntoBytesArrayOf8Bits` both use bitwise operations to traverse the integer byte by byte and copying 8 bits at a time (1 byte at a time). One returns an array of bytes with the values, and the other returns an array of integers.

Check the `getIndividualBytes` function to see a simpler way to do this, by converting the `uint256` number to a `bytes32` type (which behaves like an array for access).

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.16;

contract Contract {
    
    bytes32 public mask1 = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ff; 
    bytes32 public valueInBytes = 0x997997d543f68c7b77e62a13efc6e546bd2a81c2aa8769c3354422ebbbb4fba4;
    uint256 public valueInt = 69418702241402295221634566686862910764768312782102498574940267299320309808036;

    function getValueBrokenDownInto1Byte() public view returns(bytes1[] memory) {
        
        return break256BitsIntegerIntoBytesArrayOf1Byte(valueInt);
    }

    function getValueBrokenDownInto8Bits() public view returns(uint8[] memory) {
        return break256BitsIntegerIntoBytesArrayOf8Bits(valueInt);
    }

    function break256BitsIntegerIntoBytesArrayOf1Byte(uint256 n) public pure returns(bytes1[] memory) {

        bytes1[] memory b = new bytes1[](32);

        // Mask to copy 8 bits at a time
        // 0xff is 8 bits, so we are copying 8 bits at a time.
        // After copying 8 bits, then we need to move the ff 8 bits to the left, to be able to copy the next 8 bits
        uint256 mask = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ff;
        uint256 shiftBy = 0;

        // a 256-bit number has 32 bytes
        for(int256 i = 31; i >= 0; i--) { // Copying from right to left, end of the array to the start
            
            // Copying 8 bits of n doing an AND bitwise operation
            uint256 v = n & mask;

            // After every iteration, move the mask byte 8 bits to the left
            mask <<= 8;

            // The bits we just copied are to the left, if we try to cast v to uint8 then the bits will be lost and the result will be 0,
            // because the casting takes the lower bits (the right-most bits).
            // To prevent this, we need to shift the bits to the right-most part and then do the casting.
            // With shiftBy, we keep track of how many bits to th left we have copied and this way we can take these
            // bits to the left-most by shifting them shiftBy times.
            v >>= shiftBy;

            // Casting the bits to uint8 then to bytes1 and adding them to the b bytes array.
            b[uint(i)] = bytes1(uint8(v));
            
            // For the next interation, we need to skip the current 8 bits and copy the next 8 bits.
            shiftBy += 8;
        }

        return b;

    }

    function break256BitsIntegerIntoBytesArrayOf8Bits(uint256 n) public pure returns(uint8[] memory) {

        uint8[] memory _8BitNumbers = new uint8[](32);

        // Mask to copy 8 bits at a time
        // 0xff is 8 bits, so we are copying 8 bits at a time.
        // After copying 8 bits, then we need to move the ff 8 bits to the left, to be able to copy the next 8 bits
        uint256 mask = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ff;
        uint256 shiftBy = 0;

        // a 256-bit number has 32 bytes
        for(int256 i = 31; i >= 0; i--) { // Copying from right to left, end of the array to the start
            
            // Copying 8 bits of n doing an AND bitwise operation
            uint256 v = n & mask;

            // After every iteration, move the mask byte 8 bits to the left
            mask <<= 8;

            // The bits we just copied are to the left, if we try to cast v to uint8 then the bits will be lost and the result will be 0,
            // because the casting takes the lower bits (the right-most bits).
            // To prevent this, we need to shift the bits to the right-most part and then do the casting.
            // With shiftBy, we keep track of how many bits to th left we have copied and this way we can take these
            // bits to the left-most by shifting them shiftBy times.
            v >>= shiftBy;

            // Casting the bits to uint8 then to bytes1 and adding them to the b bytes array.
            _8BitNumbers[uint(i)] = uint8(v);
            
            // For the next interation, we need to skip the current 8 bits and copy the next 8 bits.
            shiftBy += 8;
        }

        return _8BitNumbers;

    }

    // Easy way to break down a uint256 value into an array, casting the uint256 yo a bytes32,
    // which is essencially an array, so we can access the bytes by index.
    function getIndividualBytes(uint256 n) public pure returns(bytes1[] memory) {
        bytes32 b32 = bytes32(n);
        bytes1[] memory b = new bytes1[](32);
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            b[i] = b32[i];
        }
        return b;
    }

}
```

Anyways, by uin6 I supposed you meant uin8, right? Solidity does not support uint6. A 6-bit number would only provide 64 (2^6) probable unique values, so you may have some duplicate numbers. An 8-bit number provides 256 (2^8) unique values, so, still, too small and you could get some duplicate numbers when extracting them from your 256-bit random number.
A `uint16` number provides you with 65536 (2^16) different values. So this option could be better.
A `uint32` provides you with 4294967296 (2^32) different values, and so on.
So, depending on your use case, breaking down a random `uint256` into smaller pieces could be a good source of randomness or not. But yes, if those 256 bits from Chainlink VRF are really random, then you can use them as a good source of randomness.

The larger the number, the less probable a collision.

About gas efficiency, working with bitwise operations is always cheap.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.